# Using regex to split special char

Tags: c++, c, c++11

```
string MyName = " 'hi, load1', 'hi, load2', varthatnotstring ";
```

I want to use *regex* to split the above string at every `,`, while preserving strings that are inside quotation.

As such, splitting `MyName` should yield:

```
1: 'hi, load1'
2: 'hi, load2'
3: varthatnotstring
```

I currently use `regex MyR("(.),(.),(.*)");`, but that gives me:

```
1: 'hi
2: load1'
3: 'hi
4: load2'
```

---

- What regular-expression should I use?

Comment: You should not use a regular expression. This does not seem to be a good task for regular expressions. It'd be trivial to write a simple parser by hand that searches for quoted and unquoted strings.

Comment: yes but i need to be regex .... it is very important for me to be regex ...

Comment: Why is it important that it be regex? You should strive to use the right tool for every task, so why force yourself to use one tool when another is a better fit?

Comment: ok please write for me a program with other way to do this ...

Comment: Something like `" *(('([^\']*(\\|\')*)*')|[^',]*), *"` (untested) ? (only handle `\'` and `\\` in quote).

Comment: not worked ... please check it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want to handle certain corner cases, you can use the following:

```
std::regex reg(R"--((('.*?')|[^,])+)--");
```

Step, by step:

- `R"--(...)--"` Is syntax for raw string literals, so we don't have to worry about escaping. We don't need it here, but I'm using them by default for regex strings.
- `('.*?')` all characters between (and including) two apostrophes (non greedy)
- `[^,]` anything that is not a comma
- `(('.*?')|[^,])+` arbitrary sequence of non-`,`-characters or `'...'`-sequences.
  (Note: the `('.*?')` part has to come first)

So this will also match e.g. `tkasd 'rtzrze,123'` as a single match. It will also NOT remove any whitespaces.

Usage:

```
std::regex reg(R"--((('.*?')|[^,])+)--");
std::string s = ",,t   '123,4565',k ,'rt',t,z";

for (std::sregex_iterator rit(s.begin(), s.end(), reg), end{}; rit != end; ++rit) {
    std::cout << rit->str() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
t   '123,4565'
k
'rt'
t
z
```

Edit:
I rarely use regular expressions, so any comments about possible improvements or gotchas are welcome. Maybe there is also an even better solution using `regex_token_iterator`.

Comment: Note that you cannot use `\\` or `\'` to escape `\` or `'` with your regex.

Comment: @Jarod42: Do you mean, this would e.g. be a problem if the string contains something like `don't`? You are right, I didn't think of that. Thank you!. I don't see, why `\`` would be a problem though. In any event - depending on whether the OP has control over the formatting of the string, or not - I'd rather not require them to be escaped, but would only treat `'`s special, that come directly before or after a `,` (probably allow whitespaces in between).

Comment: Yes I mean something like `don\'t`.

Comment: Ok, I'll think about it. I guess the second symbol to escape wasn't `\`` as I initially though, but the backslash itself right?

Comment: I meant: `'` (quote) , and ```\```(backslash). (I (mis-)used backquote to render those char as code...)